# Session value gets deleted if an equally named variable gets nulled

Tags: php, session

I've got the following script called index.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
$lang = "";
print_r($_SESSION);

//some other stuff

$lang = "abc";
$_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;
?>
```

On the first call, it returns as expected

```
Array () Array ()
```

On the second call (if I press F5), and this is stunning imho, this output appears:

```
Array ( [lang] => abc ) Array ()
```

The Session value with key "lang" gets emptied if I just set the variable `$lang` to `""`. Why does this happen?

EDIT: I am running PHP 5.2.17.

Comment: register_globals still active?

Comment: What value your register_global setting have?

Comment: register_globals is active - what does this mean?

Comment: I just got what it means.. But as I understood register_globals, only variables like `$lang` can be overwritten, but if I null the variable, why does it also null the session value?

Comment: Just disable it, its default value is false since PHP 4.2, deprecated in 5.3 and simply removed in 5.4 because of serious security concerns.

Comment: I've done that, thanks. May somebody write an answer to that? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php and also [What are register_globals in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593210/what-are-register-globals-in-php)

but if I want to say it simply : if `register_globals` be ON all $_POST and $_GET and $_SESSION variables will automatically copied to the variables with a same name of their index.So for example when you have a `$foo` you can't understand where it comes from ($_GET['foo'], $_SESSION['foo'], etc).

AND as @EricCitaire mentioned "Just disable it, its default value is false since PHP 4.2, deprecated in 5.3 and simply removed in 5.4 because of serious security concerns."

you can set it off using `php.ini`, `.htaccess` and also using `ini_set()`

```
ini_set('register_globals', 'Off')
```

other links:

[Dealing with register_globals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026361/dealing-with-register-globals)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

[register globals php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14117286/register-globals-php)